# How to connect to WiFi on Windows 10 using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, wifi

So, basically I took https://github.com/RRUZ/blog/tree/master/Winapi/WlanAPI and added

```
var
ConPrms : Tndu_WLAN_CONNECTION_PARAMETERS;
  Name    : WideString;
  _Result: HRESULT;
begin
....
Name := WideString('MySSID');
    ConPrms.wlanConnectionMode := wlan_connection_mode_auto;
    ConPrms.strProfile        := PWChar(Name);
    ConPrms.pDot11Ssid        := NIL;
    // Windows XP: pDesiredBssidList member must be NULL.
    ConPrms.pDesiredBssidList := NIL;
    ConPrms.dot11BssType      := dot11_BSS_type_any;
    // Windows XP: dwFlags must be set to 0
    ConPrms.dwFlags           := 0;
    _Result := WlanConnect(hClient,
                        @pInterfaceGuid,
                        @ConPrms,
                        nil);

    if _Result <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
    begin
      WriteLn('CONNECT - FAILED: ' + IntToStr(_Result) + ' - ' + SysErrorMessage(_Result));
    end;
```

in `for i := 0 to pInterface^.dwNumberOfItems - 1 do` loop.
and I am getting error `1168: Element not found` on both machines.
`netsh wlan` works just fine (I am fallowing cmd instructions here https://www.windowscentral.com/how-connect-wi-fi-network-windows-10 ). What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Use wlan_connection_mode_profile and make sure profile with that name exists.

Comment: Mike, that didn't help. I copied SSID name from cmd. Maybe I copied wrong? Then I use `ConPrms.strProfile := @pAvailableNetworkList^.Network[0].strProfileName;` (IDE hint shows it to be the same as I copied) and same error.

Comment: and dot11_BSS_type_infrastructure   AFAIR

Comment: Mike, that didn't help either. Indeed, when debugging `pAvailableNetworkList^.Network[0].dot11BssType` says it is dot11_BSS_type_infrastructure, but code still produces 1168.

Comment: The only problem I can see it profile name. Rae you sure that profile name is exactly the same and profile exists? Try to enumerate profiles (you can do it easy with WiFi Client from this https://www.btframework.com/wififramework.htm).

Comment: Oh, by the way, do not forget about encoding! If profile has non-ascii chars (or network name has non-ascii chars) it may bring problems.

Comment: From those fragments and from the code example on GitHub; if `pInterfaceGuid` is a pointer to GUID (`PGUID`), then the `WlanConnect` function needs just that (depending how is imported), not a pointer to it (not `@pInterfaceGuid`, but `pInterfaceGuid`). The same may apply to the connection parameters, but all that is a guess as here we have only fragments, not a complete, minimal code (including just used type declarations and function imports).

Comment: TLama, thats it! Thank you.